# Is there a way to use query string and object, together, inside $.post data argument?

Tags: jquery, jquery-post

I'm using $.post to send data to the server.
There are 4 values that I want to send, two from a form, and two that I've written inside the function:

```
    var desc = $('textarea[name="image_description"]').fieldSerialize();
    var album = $('select[name="album"]').fieldSerialize();
```

and the other two I was just putting into an Object

```
{a:"something", b:"something else"}
```

I know I could just get the values of the form elements and add them to the object that way, but 
I was wondering if there was an easy way to combine these two types (ie query string and object) into the data argument?

Comment: There is a way where you populate hidden fields with you data before you post or you can concat the object to the serialized data. So it looks like `field1=data1&field2=data2&a=something&b=something%20%else`, i think.

Comment: Thanks, @limelights. I've ended just grabbing the values of the form elements and adding them into the data object. I just though it would be a good question to put up for other people, and, i guess, I just wanted to know if there was a special way to do it :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.serialize() return string which means you can append your additional values from functions.

```
var data = $("#yourForm").serialize() + "&a=something&b=else";
```

I think it is easy and enough to solve your question but if you need more special way to do it, take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/.

so you can do things like

```
var myObject = {
 a: "something",
 b: "else"
};

var moreValues = $.param(myObject);

var data = $("#yourForm").serialize() + "&" + moreValues;
```